# How the parent's folder and its last file get deleted using this recursive function in foreach loop?

Tags: php, recursion, foreach

I am deleting a parent folder and its all content (files and sub-folders with content) using a recursive function within a `foreach` loop.

Though the code is working pretty fine but I'm not able to understand how the parent folder and its last file are deleted.

The file structure is:

[image]

The code is:

```
<?php
function delete_dir($dir)
{
    if(is_dir($dir))
    {
        $files = scandir($dir);

        foreach($files as $file)
        {
            if($file != "." && $file != "..")
            {
                if(filetype($dir . "/" . $file) == "dir")
                {
                    delete_dir($dir . "/" . $file);
                }
                else
                {
                    unlink($dir . "/" . $file);     
                }
            }
        }

        rmdir($dir);
    }
}

$dir = "../files";
delete_dir($dir);
?>
```

When `delete_dir()` function runs first time, `$files` has following content:

```
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => Apple Logo.png
    [3] => customers.csv
    [4] => sunset.jpg
    [5] => test
    [6] => test.txt
)
```

When code sees `test` folder, it then calls `delete_dir()` function recursively and then following content of `test` folder is deleted:

```
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => Google Logo.png
    [3] => sachin.txt
)
```

But I'm not able to understand how `test.txt` (last file of parent folder) and the parent folder `files` itself get deleted since the code execution has come out of `foreach` loop of recursive function.

Can anyone help me in understanding the flow related to deletion of `test.txt` and `files`?

Comment: What do you mean with "since the code execution has come out of foreach"? The recursive call happens inside foreach. After that it will return exactly there and continue inside the foreach-loop, to handle "test.txt" in the next iteration.

Comment: @simon.ro Oh ok! that's the point I was missing out. I misunderstood recursive function functionality in loop. So after deleting the content of subfolder and subfolder itself, the code resumes from the point it left it in the foreach loop to delete remaining files in the parent folder and then delete parent folder also.

Comment: So in short the loop is put on pause when the recursive function is called within the loop and then resumes again once recursion is over. Am I right with all these my points?

Comment: yes, exactly. A recursive call behaves no differently than any other function call: the function is executed and then the program continues at the point of the call. If that point is in a loop, the program will continue in the loop...

Answer (score 0):

When calling the delete_dir() function within the delete_dir() function you are creating a second foreach loop (as you said, recursive). So what actually happens in order is:

1. Apple Logo.png

   - unlink
2. customers.csv

   - unlink
3. sunset.jpg

   - unlink
4. test

   - delete_dir (second foreach)

     1. Google Logo.png

        - unlink
     2. Google Logo.png

        - unlink
5. test.txt

   - unlink

Now the first foreach has finally finished and calls rmdir() on the original input, which is:

```
$dir = "../files";
```

Comment: same file is written twice in second foreach loop.

Comment: Yeah copy paste erro, should've been sachin.txt :)